VB.Net, How can I get the name and value of a variable passed into a function?
Using the method in the first answer of this question, I can get name of passed variables : How can I get the name of a variable passed into a function?
I need both name and value. How could I call the closure inside ExampleFunction ?
Dim aaaa As String = "test1234"
Dim bbbb = ExampleFunction(Function() aaaa) ' bbbb is "aaaa" , but I need "aaaa: test1234"

Public Function ExampleFunction(f As Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of String)))
    Return DirectCast(f.Body, Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression).Member.Name.Split("_")(1)
End Function


That other answer got both value (in the 'real' variable) and its name in an extra one - the example checks that the variable has a value, and mentions its name when not

Yes, that's true. But I want to somehow call f() inside ExampleFunction and get "test1234"
